# Correct tenses with usage of never

Tags: tense

Which ones are correct?

1. I have never thought of getting married until now.
2. I never thought of getting married until now.
3. I had never thought of getting married until now.
4. I have never visited Italy until this week.
5. I had never visited Italy until this week.

Comment: What if you're going to Italy tomorrow or next week?

Answer (score 1):

1. I **had** never thought of getting married until now.
2. I **[had]** never thought of getting married until now.

> **3.** I had never thought of getting married until now. **Correct**

4. I **had** never visited Italy until this week.

> **5.** I had never visited Italy until this week. **Correct**

It is an example of the [past perfect](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html). I shall include the content in case the link expires.

> Past Perfect expresses the idea that something occurred before another action in the past. It can also show that something happened before a specific time in the past.
>
> Examples:
>
> I had never seen such a beautiful beach before I went to Kauai.
>
> I did not have any money because I had lost my wallet.
>
> Tony knew Istanbul so well because he had visited the city several times.
>
> Had Susan ever studied Thai before she moved to Thailand?
>
> She only understood the movie because she had read the book.
>
> Kristine had never been to an opera before last night.

Comment: What if you say the words as the plane is landing in Rome, and you use the phrase "until this very moment"? Would the past perfect and "until this very moment" be idiomatic together?